# pandas filter Series with a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series and a list like this

```
$ import pandas as pd 

$ s = pd.Series(data=[1, 2, 3, 4], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
$ filter_list = ['A', 'C', 'D']

$ print(s)

A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
```

How can I create a new Series with row `B` removed using `s` and `filter_list`?

I mean I want to create a Series `new_s` with the following content

```
$ print(new_s)

A    1
C    3
D    4
```

`s.isin(filter_list)` doesn't work. Because I want to filter based on the index of the Series, not the values of the Series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) if all values of list exist in index:

```
new_s = s.loc[filter_list]
print (new_s)
A    1
C    3
D    4
dtype: int64
```

If possible some not exist use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) or `isin` like @Yusuf Baktir solution:

```
filter_list = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']
new_s = s.loc[s.index.intersection(filter_list)]
print (new_s)
A    1
C    3
D    4
dtype: int64
```

Another alternative with [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
filter_list = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']
new_s = s[np.in1d(s.index, filter_list)]
print (new_s)
A    1
C    3
D    4
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, those are the index values. So, filtering on index will work

```
s[s.index.isin(filter_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in filter_list: 
     print(i,s[i]) 

A 1
C 3
D 4
```